# Client with TLS 1.0 calling TLS 1.2 thought NGINX

Tags: ssl, nginx, tls1.2

I have a **Client Y** running under Windows Server 2003 that only supports TLS 1.0 (.NET Framework 3.5) and I have a **Service X** running under Linux (Java 1.8) with NGINX, that accepts connection only with TLS 1.2.

```
Client Y (TLS 1.0) ---> calls ---> Service X (TLS 1.2 over Nginx).
```

This is my NGINX config:

```
# HTTPS server
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name myapi.com.br;
  ssl_certificate  /etc/pki/tls/certs/myfile.cer;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/myfile.key;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

But it didn't work, the Client Y can't call the Service X, but another Client Z using TLS 1.2 can call the Service X without problem.

This is the error in nginx:

```
2019/08/06 11:23:18 [crit] 25199#0: *253185 SSL_shutdown() failed (SSL: error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init) while SSL handshaking, client: 10.31.68.186, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Comment: So you either need to update the client to support TLS 1.2, or have nginx re-configured to allow TLS 1.0 via `ssl_protocols` directive. What's the question?

Comment: I tried re-configured nginx to use support TLS 1.0, with the following: ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; But didn't work.